# Charge my Mac via USB

Tags: macbook-pro, power, charger

I have a portable power bank and I can charge devices via USB on it. Is there an adapter to change a 3 prong charger to a USB, so I can plug my Mac into my power bank? A Mac air charger that can plug into a USB port would work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Most MacBook use MagSafe charging which doesn't operate on the same voltage as USB - so the vast majority of battery banks that charge anything USB won't work. There are some inverters that would power the **adapter** using 120 or 240 VAC but those are quite large.

Only the new MacBook with USB-C connector is low power enough to charge over the new power delivery specification for USB 3.1 that generally is supported along with the change to USB-C connector. Any charging bank would need increased power than what is used to charge most any mobile devices made in 2015 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Standard USB ports can not handle the load of power that a Macbook Air/Pro draws. So no, it is not advisable even if you could find an adapter. (Note that if you have the new ultrathin Macbook—not the Air or Pro—you can use a USB-C to USB2 cable to charge it from a power bank.)

You can get a special power bank (like [this one](http://www.lenmar.com/chugplug)) that can charge your Macbook Air via Magsafe.

Comment: Is that possible? The new MacBook uses the 20V lines on The USB-C. I'm not aware of a standard step-up circuit for USB-A to USB-C for power transferral.

Comment: The special bank linked above inverts DC battery to 120 VAC and then powers the normal adapter. Those electronics are common. I have seen some attempts to provide DC directly to the magsafe adapter or DIY splicing of the wiring - but those are far less common.